# Does binding a click event to a button that already has a click event bound cause issues?

Tags: jquery

Does binding a click event to a button that already has a click event bound cause issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You will now have two click events on that button. Both will happen in order they were bound.

Try out this simple example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/FQvJq/

```
$('#test')
    .click(function(){ alert('click callback 1')})
    .click(function(){ alert('click callback 2')})
```

Answer (score 4):

No, the [events accumulate](http://jsfiddle.net/VcCNy/).

Comment: that jsfiddle.net seems pretty neat :)

Comment: @VoodooChild, yes it's very nice for writing mockups.

Answer (score 0):

Technically no, but it depends more on what your events are doing. They will execute in sequence. Id think more about what impact the two events could have on one another.

Its also perhaps worth binding defined methods to the events as this will make for easier unbinding - even if it doesn't apply to you its still better design, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

As of **jQuery 1.4.2** duplicate event handlers can be bound to an element instead of being discarded. For example:

```
function test(){ alert("Hello"); }
$("button").click( test );
$("button").click( test );
```

The above will generate two alerts when the button is clicked.

In **jQuery 1.4.3** you can now pass in 'false' in place of an event handler. This will bind an event handler that's equivalent to: `function(){ return false; }`. This function can be removed at a later time by calling: `.unbind( eventName, false )`.

I think this might be helpful you.**Thanks**